# After Wordpress update, links stop working when clicked on

Tags: wordpress, url, updates, permalinks

I’ve launched a staging woo-commerce website on my localhost (XAMPP), which is running well on **Wordpress 5.5.6**. But whenever I update WP core to newer versions, internal links (incl. posts, products, etc.) suddenly stop opening when clicked on, and I’m left no choice but right-clicking and opening them in new tab.
I’ve tried any possible way to debug the issue, but to no avail: from creating a fresh **.htaccess** file to deactivating **plugins**, deactivating the **Block Editor**, installing “**Enable jQuery Migrate Helper**” plugin, etc.
So I don’t know how to get rid of this frustrating, weird problem. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What happens when you click the links? Do you get 404 errors? Do the links work if you disabled permalinks in WordPress settings?

Comment: @veesar Nothing happens when clicked on and I get no error. I'll disable permalinks, as you've suggested, to see what happens and will make you updated

Comment: I just reset permalinks, but the problem still remains @veesar

Comment: If there are no 404 or any other errors, can you check if the links are still valid or if they've been stripped of the `<a>` tags? Please provide the link to your site if available.

Comment: Links are valid as long as I right-click and open them in new tab; but when they are clicked on directly, nothing happens. I'm working on localhost, that's why I couldn't provide a link to the site. here is the same problem a user had encountered some months ago: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/links-not-working-after-latest-update/ @veesar

Comment: I finally could solve the issue! A rather old, nulled plugin (related to ajax add to cart) was at the heart of the problem. Interestingly, I had deactivated all the plugins at once, including this troublemaking one, for troubleshooting the problem. But it was no enough. This plugin, though deactivated, had made some changes to my database by adding a new table. So it was necessary to uninstall the plugin and drop its table to solve this riddle.